# Strange behavior when parsing result from curl + awk

Tags: bash, jenkins, awk

Using curl on ubuntu I am trying to fetch the Jenkins version inspired by:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

In a bash script I do:

```
VERSION=$(curl -k -i -X GET --insecure --silent --header \"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN \" $URL | grep -Fi X-Jenkins: | awk '{print $2}')
echo "__A__[${VERSION}]__B__"
```

But when I run the script I get:

```
]__B__2.89.2
```

So for some reason the prefix: `__A__[` gets swallowed and the *suffix* gets turned into a *prefix*.

I have also tried to trim the output with:

```
VERSION=$(curl -k -i -X GET --insecure --silent --header \"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN \" $URL | grep -Fi X-Jenkins: | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
```

But it gives the same result.

As suggested below I have also tried with:

```
echo '__A__['"${VERSION}"']__B__'
```

But still gives the same/wrong result.

A few other things I have tried (giving the same result)

**Same/wrong output**

```
VERSION=$(curl -k -i -X GET --insecure --silent --header \"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN \" $URL | grep -i X-Jenkins: | awk '{print $2}')
echo '__A__['"${VERSION}"']__B__'
```

**Same/wrong output**

```
VERSION=$(curl -k -i -X GET --insecure --silent --header \"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN \" $URL | grep X-Jenkins: | awk '{print $2}')
echo '__A__['"${VERSION}"']__B__'
```

Based on below suggestion I have now tried:

```
echo $VERSION|od -ax
```

Which gives:

```
0000000   2   .   8   9   .   2  cr  nl
           2e32    3938    322e    0a0d
0000010
```

If I compare that with:

```
VERSION_TEMP="2.89.2"
echo $VERSION_TEMP|od -ax
```

I get:

```
0000000   2   .   8   9   .   2  nl
           2e32    3938    322e    000a
0000007
```

So looks like its the cr in the VERSION var that is causing the issue (not sure how that explains the whole reversing of prefix/suffix as described above).

**SOLVED:** Based on input from Romeo I now got it to work with adding `|tr -d '\r'` :

```
VERSION=$(curl -k -i -X GET --insecure --silent --header \"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN \" $URL | grep X-Jenkins: | awk '{print $2}'|tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: Do you need `-F` in `grep`?

Comment: I have tried to remove both -F and -i to grep, same result, see updated post.

Comment: Try to dump the binary data in VERSION variable `echo $VERSION|od -ax` to check for strange symbols inside.

Comment: The escaped double quotes around the `--header` argument can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the output contains a DOS carriage return.

Try adding `tr -d '\015'`:

```
version=$(curl -k -i -X GET --insecure --silent --header \"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN \" "$URL" |
    tr -d '\015' |
   awk 'tolower($0) !~ /x-jenkins:/{print $2}')
echo "__A__[$version]__B__"
```

Uppercase variable names are reserved for system use, so I changed yours to lower case, too, and removed the [useless `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)